# How do I fix REJECT NON FAST FORWARD error on Github? 

Tags: linux, git, netbeans, github

Yesterday and for about months I was able to push/commit. But since few hours ago I cannot commit and push in my own private repository anymore. I have 2 new collaborator, and they have same problem as me.

How to resolve this?

1. tried pulling before push
2. tried commit and it always says local conflict need to be resolved
3. Then i resolved local conflict and accepted all
4. Again it says push failed which is annoying error all the time now

Everytime it says hat follow result.

```
==[IDE]== Feb 7, 2012 11:33:21 AM Pushing
git push git@github.com:a/b.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
git push git@github.com:a/b.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Remote Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : f3b00695638eec 
New Id : c79bc1a4650 
Result : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
Branch : origin/master
Old Id : f3b00695 
New Id : c79bc1a4650e02 
Result : NOT_ATTEMPTED

==[IDE]== Feb 7, 2012 11:34:34 AM Pushing finished.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you run git status after 3rd step. I think you need to run git commit after 3rd step and then go for 4th one.

Comment: After 3rd setp when did and again did he git commit it says again local is broken, resolve first. And after resolve and over and over fails to push.